# Unable to use make in alpine image

Tags: docker, makefile, alpine-linux

I cant get `make` to work in alpine
`make update_tools` works when I run it on my OSX, but when i run it in the alpine image i get the following error:
make: *** No rule to make target 'update_tools'. Stop.
Here is what my Dockerfile looks like now:

```
#Download base image Alpine-3.9  Golang 1.12 
FROM golang:1.12-alpine3.9

# Set Working Directory is /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install Alpine Dependencies
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --update alpine-sdk && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh make cmake 

COPY cosmos-sdk .

WORKDIR /usr/app/cosmos-sdk

RUN git checkout v0.33.0 && \
    make update_tools && \ 
    make vendor-deps && \ 
    make install && \
    gaiad init $(whoami) && \
    rm .gaiad/config/genesis.json && \
    curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmos/launch/master/genesis.json > $HOME/.gaiad/config/genesis.json 

#Add persistent peer to config.toml file
RUN sed -i '' 's/persistent_peers = ""/persistent_peers = "89e4b72625c0a13d6f62e3cd9d40bfc444cbfa77@34.65.6.52:26656"/' $HOME/.gaiad/config/config.toml 

#Start gaid daemon and set logging to info
CMD ["gaiad start --log_level="*:info""]

# Expose the ports
EXPOSE 26656 26657
```

### Makefile: https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/develop/Makefile

I would appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: Can you post your Makefile?

Comment: Shared @michalhosna

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Am having this issue.

It seems something from the golang-alpine image itself.

** --- Solution --- **

just install the make in your image as following:

`apk add --no-cache make`

Answer (score -1):

Direct clone and checkout v0.33.0 doesn't have mentioned problem. It looks like a problem with `git checkout v0.33.0` command. Probably you have uncommitted changes. Please check/provide `docker build` output.

Answer (score -1):

had a similar issue, make sure your Makefile is added to the docker image, mine Makefile was added to .dockerignore file, so it was not present in docker image and I got a similar error message